# AspNetBoilerplate (Free version + .NET Core + Angular): redirect to home from login page if user is already logged in

Tags: .net, angular, aspnetboilerplate

How to redirect from login page to home page if user is already logged in?
Currently:

a) if user is logged in and if I enter url like "`localhost:2222`" user is automatically redirected to `/app/home`

b) if user is already logged in, but he is entering login page with `url` like "`localhost:2222/account/login`" user is not redirect to Home instead. We wish him to be redirected to `/app/home` also in this scenario.

So, user would need to logout first if he wants to see login page.

We use AspNetBoileplrate .NET Core with Angular (not Premium)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your check in `RouteGuard`

For example:

```
if (this._sessionService.user && state.url === 'account/login') {
    this._router.navigate(['app/home']);
    return false;
}
```

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/164a5c9e28cb29383551d0f3310986ab43d0ceed/angular/src/shared/auth/auth-route-guard.ts#L21